# Eliminar el ultimo commit Git

Tags: git, git-commit

¿Como puedo eliminar el ultimo commit en un repositorio?

Tengo un repositorio en dev azure, e hice un commit incluyendo el archivo del `web.config` ( que no debería de haber subido por error ), así que use el `git revert` para revertir los cambios pero en el repositorio aún me sigue apareciendo ese historial del commit.

¿Como puedo eliminar eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que con `git reset HEAD~1`

Comment: pues si funciona pero es cuando no haz hecho el push al repositorio

Comment: Alguna de estas: [Git revert commit already pushed to Remote](https://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html)